# How to change the Code view theme on Dreamweaver cc 2014.1

Tags: themes, dreamweaver

I've just updated to Dreamweaver cc 2014.1 through Creative Cloud and I've been trying to change to a [Monokai theme](http://www.xenon-webdesign.co.uk/dev/dark-code-view-theme-color-scheme-dreamweaver-cs3-sublime-text-skin/) I've downloaded. I replaced the Colors.xml file in Code Coloring, restarted Dreamweaver but still wasn't working. Help!

Answer (score 0):

As of CC 2014.1, Dreamweaver now uses Themes for color coding. Hooray! Check it out in Dreamweaver > Preferences > Code Coloring > Theme, there's a popup list of theme names that you can choose from. Good start! Oddly, there were one or two I tried from the list which had some attributes/tags that were impossible to read on the theme's background. But, it wouldn't be a new Adobe feature without some glaring lack of QA. Luckily, you can alter the theme's color settings, and you can restore them to the theme's defaults! BUT you can't create a new theme or duplicate an existing one from within this preference pane! Why? Because Adobe.

However, Adobe has provided instructions on how to do it the long way yourself! Hooray for the scenic route:

https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/setting-coding-preferences.html#set_the_code_colors (see 'Add themes to the default list')

> Add themes to the default list
>   If you want a customized theme to appear in the default theme list, perform the following steps:
>
> Copy and paste Themes.xml to your desktop from the following location:
>
> On Win: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015\configuration\themes
>   On Mac: Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015/configuration/themes/
>   Open Themes.xml in Notepad and add the following line before the closing tag :
>
> ```
> <theme name="MyTheme"></theme>
> ```
>
> Replace the Themes.xml file in the following location with the file you edited:
>
> On Win: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015\configuration\themes
>   On Mac: Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015/configuration/themes/
>   To specify the color scheme for your theme, reuse the XML files for the existing themes in the following locations:
>
> On Win: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015\configuration\themes 
>   On Mac: Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015/configuration/themes/
>   For example, copy Raven.xml and defaultColorsRaven.xml, and then rename the copied files to MyTheme.xml and defaultColorsMyTheme.xml.
>
> Relaunch Dreamweaver and check the default themes list (Preferences > Code Coloring) to see if your theme is listed.

The first time I did this, I made the mistake of messing with the files in ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CC 2014.1/en_US/Configuration/Themes/ as I had been digging around in the CodeColoring folder in the Library as you were above if you were on a Mac — however these just seem to be copies of the themes (and doesn't include Themes.xml). Not sure if those are backups or what, but be sure you're editing the correct files located in Applications (Mac) or Program Files (Win).

Now the ~/Library/[etc]/CodeColoring/Colors.xml and defaultColors.xml files seem to get written to to save your current settings for whatever theme you're using. So don't touch those. And there is another CodeColoring folder in the Application folder with all the old XML files like Colors.xml, CodeColoring.xml, which as far as I can tell do nothing as they haven't been modified since I've been messing with all this. Probably legacy garbage files.

Now for the existing color themes out there, it looks like you're in luck! They follow the same format as the MyTheme.xml file. So you'll just need to rename the Colors.xml file to Monokai.xml, add a line in Themes.xml for Monokai as instructed above, and now you're just missing a defaultColorsMonokai.xml, which you can just copy from another similarly colored theme and rename. Restart Dreamweaver and you've got your theme installed.

Just FYI, there's an included theme called Monaki so don't get confused by that. They'll display in the theme list in the order presented in the Themes.xml file.

I'm not sure why I still use Dreamweaver over say another code editor/site manager that doesn't cause my discrete GPU to kick in every time, but here's to small improvements, if you can call this one. Maybe next year we'll get a simple way to install 3rd party themes or dupe/create our own in the preference pane!